# Using custom HandlerMethodMappingNamingStrategy in Spring MVC

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc

In Spring MVC each end point is automatically assigned a name by a `HandlerMethodMappingNamingStrategy`, by default this is done by `RequestMappingInfoHandlerMethodMappingNamingStrategy` which will use the capital letters of a controller, the pound sign (#) and then the method name of the end point.

So a controller named `HomeController` which has a method `index` will automatically be assigned the mappingName `HC#index`.

I want to provide my own strategy, whereby the FULL controller name is used, so it would generate the mapping name `HomeController#index`.

The Spring MVC documentation is quite clear and says:

> Here is how this works. On startup, every @RequestMapping is assigned
> a default name through HandlerMethodMappingNamingStrategy, whose
> default implementation uses the capital letters of the class and the
> method name (for example, the getThing method in ThingController
> becomes "TC#getThing"). If there is a name clash, you can use
> @RequestMapping(name="..") to assign an explicit name or implement
> your own HandlerMethodMappingNamingStrategy.

I've created my own class that implements `HandlerMethodMappingNamingStrategy` but I have no idea how this can now be picked up by Spring MVC.

The only place I see the default strategy referenced in the Spring code is in an abstract class which will instantiate the default strategy directly:

```
public abstract class RequestMappingInfoHandlerMapping extends AbstractHandlerMethodMapping<RequestMappingInfo> {
    
    ...other code

    protected RequestMappingInfoHandlerMapping() {
        setHandlerMethodMappingNamingStrategy(new RequestMappingInfoHandlerMethodMappingNamingStrategy());
    }

    ...other code

}
```

Answer (score 1):

for this scenario you must use the **name** property within **@RequestMapping**

> Assign a name to this mapping. Supported at the type level as well as at the method level! When used on both levels, a combined name is derived by concatenation with "#" as separator.

Comment: It's possible to do it manually, but the documentation is quite clear and says that you can provide your own HandlerMethodMappingNamingStrategy, which means I shouldn't have to do it manually for each individual end point

Answer (score 0):

so you should do it like this

```
public class CustomHandlerMethodMappingNamingStrategy implements HandlerMethodMappingNamingStrategy<RequestMappingInfo> {
    private static final String SEPARATOR = "#";
    @Override
    public String getName(@NotNull HandlerMethod handlerMethod, RequestMappingInfo mapping) {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        if (Objects.nonNull(mapping.getName())){
            return mapping.getName();
        }
        sb.append(handlerMethod.getBeanType().getSimpleName())
            .append(SEPARATOR)
            .append(handlerMethod.getMethod().getName());
        return sb.toString();
    }
}
```

and then you must create a method annotated with **@Bean** and **@Qualifier("HandlerMethodMappingNamingStrategy")** which the spring container will then inject into its implementation. below is the example:

```
@Bean
@Qualifier("HandlerMethodMappingNamingStrategy")
public HandlerMethodMappingNamingStrategy<RequestMappingInfo> customHandlerMethodMappingNamingStrategy() {
        return new CustomHandlerMethodMappingNamingStrategy();
}
```

Comment: This is what I tried, but it doesn't work. Which is why I went digging into the Spring source code and noticed that Spring isn't using a Spring bean to set the strategy, but simply creates a new instance of the RequestMappingInfoHandlerMethodMappingNamingStrategy, as you can see in the code snippet I posted in the original question